# Redirect using Nginx based on url

Tags: docker, nginx, identityserver4, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I need to redirect if the user is not authenticated and using Identityserver4 as authentication.

If Nginx server is hit with

1. `https://example.com/auth` needs to redirect to internal server `http://authserver.example.com/request_uri` (need to trim /auth also)
2. if the URI does not start with `/auth` redirect to internal server `http://api.example.com/request_uri`

I tried  the below

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/localhost.key;

    location /auth {
        rewrite ^/auth(.*) 192.168.1.6:5001$1 permanent ;
        return 301;
     }

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://web-api;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
```

But end up with a loop in Nginx server